# JRuby: Rake fails with Gem::Version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, jruby, rubygems, jrubyonrails

I get the following error on any call to rake.  I am working on a Rails 3 running on JRuby (1.5.1) installed with RVM.  I don't think this was always the case, but I'm not sure how to track it down.  Am I correct in think this has something to do with the gems I have installed (listing included below)?

```
$ rake metrics:all
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.1@backend/bin/rake: line 9: require: command not found
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.1@backend/bin/rake: line 11: version: command not found
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.1@backend/bin/rake: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/Eric/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.5.1@backend/bin/rake: line 13: `if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then'


*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta4)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta4)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta4)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta4)
activerecord-jdbc-adapter (0.9.7)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta4)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta4)
arel (0.4.0)
arrayfields (4.7.4)
autotest (4.3.2)
autotest-growl (0.2.4)
autotest-rails (4.1.0)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.26)
capybara (0.3.9)
chronic (0.2.3)
churn (0.0.12)
configuration (1.1.0)
cucumber (0.8.3)
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
culerity (0.2.10)
database_cleaner (0.5.2)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
factory_girl (1.3.1)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
fattr (2.1.0)
ffi (0.6.3)
flay (1.4.0)
flog (2.2.0)
gherkin (2.0.2)
hirb (0.3.2)
hoe (2.6.1)
hoptoad_notifier (2.3.2)
i18n (0.4.1)
jdbc-mysql (5.0.4)
jruby-openssl (0.7)
json (1.4.3)
json-jruby (1.4.3.1)
json_pure (1.4.3)
launchy (0.3.5)
mail (2.2.5)
main (4.2.0)
mechanize (1.0.0)
mime-types (1.16)
nokogiri (1.4.2)
open_gem (1.4.2)
pickle (0.3.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.6)
rack-test (0.5.4)
rails (3.0.0.beta4)
railties (3.0.0.beta4)
rake (0.8.7)
rcov (0.9.8)
rdoc (2.5.9)
redis (2.0.3)
redis-namespace (0.7.0)
resque (1.9.7)
rspec (2.0.0.beta.16, 1.3.0)
rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.16)
rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.16)
rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.16)
rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.16)
ruby_parser (2.0.4)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
rvm (0.1.41)
Saikuro (1.1.0)
selenium-webdriver (0.0.24)
sexp_processor (3.0.4)
shoulda (2.11.1)
sinatra (1.0)
spork (0.8.4)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
thor (0.13.7)
treetop (1.4.8)
trollop (1.16.2)
tzinfo (0.3.22)
vegas (0.1.7)
weakling (0.0.4)
webrat (0.7.1)
ZenTest (4.3.3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is interpreting the bin/rake script as a Bash script, not a Ruby script. You might check the shebang line at the top of bin/rake and/or reinstall rake. If that fails to fix the issue, you can run like `jruby -S rake` instead.